# Is there a way to convert relative time like "now-1d" to absolute time in elasticsearch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, kibana

I am writing a plugin for Kibana.
I want to display a chart:

```
<Chart>
  <Axis
    id="bottom"
    title={dateFormatter(startDate)}
    position={Position.Bottom}
    tickFormat={dateFormatter}
  />
  <Axis
    id="left"
    position={Position.Left}
    tickFormat={(d: any) =>
      Number(d).toFixed(0)
    }
  />
  <BarSeries
    id="data"
    xScaleType={ScaleType.Time}
    yScaleType={ScaleType.Linear}
    xAccessor={["x"]}
    yAccessors={["y"]}
    stackAccessors={["x"]}
    data={chartData}
  /> 
</Chart>
```

In the horizontal axis (the first Axis in the above code), I want to show the title as Date, for example, 12 August 2023. The date is
got from the EUI Date picker. It has startDate and endDate. When the format in Date picker is relative (like "Last 30 days"), startDate and endDate are like "now-30d" and "now".
This case, dateFormatter(startDate) returns "Invalid date".
If the format in Date picker is changed to Absolute, then dateFormatter(startDate) is what I want: 12 August 2023.

So, if I can convert the relative date "now-30d" to absolute date, my problem will be solved. It seems that this kind of relative date is specific to elasticsearch.

So the question is how to convert relative time format like "now-30d"  to absolute date/time format.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, need to have more information. Please clarify the request and share what you did so far with examples.

Comment: Hi, I modified the question. Hopefully, the question is more clear now.